# How to delete huge duplicate data except one record without identical column/Primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to delete duplicate rows in a table when no primary key
is defined(Non normalised DB).

My problem is - My table has approx 540 million records. Previously I used CTE to delete the records but it was taking time more than 8 hours. I want to optimize the query.
For example: If we have table1 with data as below,

```
ID FNAME LNAME 
1 AAA CCC
2 BBB DDD
1 AAA CCC
2 BBB DDD
1 AAA CCC
2 BBB DDD
3 BCB DGD
```

Remove duplicate rows and keep the data in to the table like this using single query.

```
ID FNAME LNAME
1 AAA CCC
2 BBB DDD
3 BCB DGD
```

Previously I applied this type of query-

```
;with TBLCTE(EmpID,Ranking)
AS
(
select
EmpID,
Ranking = DENSE_RANK() over (PARTITION BY EmpID order by newID())
from @TBL
)
delete from TBLCTE where Ranking > 1
select * from @TBL order by EmpID
```

But it is taking too much time.

I want a solution which answer these conditions:

1. No primary key or identical column
2. Data is more then 540 million, query should take less time to delete the records.

Comment: What do you mean by 54 crore?

Comment: Can you add some indexes?

Comment: @wewesthemenace https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crore

Comment: @Arvo, cool. I thought it was a typo.

Comment: just insert the result set into temp table and truncate main table because it doesn't have any keys and reinsert into main table

Comment: Or use `SELECT INTO`, drop the original table then rename the newly created table.

Comment: like Arvo mentioned, an index on `EmpID` should help if you don't have that already.

Comment: @wewesthemenace - Nice Idea, a `DELETE` on this size of data will most likely fillup the transaction log as well

Comment: I have never tried, but would a new table with ignore_dup_key index + select into it (or bcp or something like that) work?

Comment: Please try my suggestion about transferring by the chunks It is also a good idea to create index for fields FNAME and LNAME for both tables before executing of the script

Comment: Create 26 tables with (ID, FNAME, LNAME) as primary key. All FNAME's starting with A from the main table will have to be inserted into table A and so on. Ignore unique constraint violations while inserting. Since each of the 26 tables will have about 20 million rows, they may be manageable. Finally combine them. This can be parallellized. If 26 is too many, the same approach can be used with say, 10 tables. Or with one table with 26 partitions, with locally partitioned indexes.

Comment: Also, you could try the SSIS Import / Export like I described in my latest update in the answer. It is supposed to be one of the fastest options for transferring big amount of data

Answer (score 1):

Transferring into the NewTable data from an OldTable by chunks:

```
DECLARE @ChunkSize INT = 1000;

WHILE (EXISTS(
    SELECT TOP(1)1 FROM OldTable ot 
    WHERE 
        NOT EXISTS(
            SELECT TOP(1) 1 
              FROM NewTable nt 
            WHERE 
              nt.FNAME = ot.FNAME AND nt.LNAME = ot.LNAME)))
BEGIN

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;


        INSERT INTO NewTable(FNAME, LNAME)
        SELECT DISTINCT TOP(@ChunkSize) 
            FNAME, LNAME
          FROM 
            OldTable ot 
        WHERE 
            NOT EXISTS(
                SELECT TOP(1) 1 
                  FROM NewTable nt 
                WHERE 
                    nt.FNAME = ot.FNAME AND 
                    nt.LNAME = ot.LNAME);

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;

END;
```

Clear source table

```
TRUNCATE TABLE OldTable;
```

Transferring data back to OldTable

```
WHILE (EXISTS(
    SELECT TOP(1)1 FROM NewTable nt 
    WHERE 
        NOT EXISTS(
            SELECT TOP(1) 1 
              FROM OldTable ot 
            WHERE 
              nt.FNAME = ot.FNAME AND nt.LNAME = ot.LNAME)))
BEGIN

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;


        INSERT INTO OldTable(FNAME, LNAME)
        SELECT DISTINCT TOP(@ChunkSize) 
            FNAME, LNAME
          FROM 
            NewTable nt 
        WHERE 
            NOT EXISTS(
                SELECT TOP(1) 1 
                  FROM OldTable ot 
                WHERE 
                    nt.FNAME = ot.FNAME AND 
                    nt.LNAME = ot.LNAME);

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;

END;
```

Clear transfer table:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE NewTable;

SELECT TOP(1000) * FROM OldTable
```

Result:

[image]

I think using of SSIS the fastest way to transfer data to another table and then return them back.

Try right mouse button click on your DB, Tasks->Import data. Then select same DB as the data source and choose "Write custom query..." option: SELECT DISTINCT FNAME, LNAME FROM Old Table and choose NewTable as destination table.

And finally, run an import

Comment: Hi..Can you please tell me how the subquery is working in this. I did not understand the 'not exists' use here. Thanks for all help

Comment: Hello. We check existing records in source table which does not exist in target table and then we transfer them by chunks. Exists checks what query returns results

Comment: I agree, that exist will check for records that are matching between source and destination and will not insert those records again.
but WHERE NOT EXISTS 1? How does this justify the insertion? what does 1 denotes?

Comment: Not exists is opposite to exists. I. e. we check what no one record which matches criteria exists. 1 means what for us doesn't need any fields in SELECT statement You can put any number or string here instead of 1, but I prefer to use 1 for it to keep it simple.

Comment: It depends on indexes, but it supposed to be faster than ordinary select. Could you create indexes for both tables?

Comment: Like this:
    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [TableNameFnameLname] ON     [TableName]
    (
     [FNAME] ASC,
     [LNAME] ASC
    );

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83874/discussion-between-stepan-novikov-and-aashi).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 WITH TempId AS (
 SELECT *, 
 row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY ID, FNAME,LNAME ORDER BY ID) AS [Num]
 FROM Employee)

DELETE TempId WHERE [Num] > 1

Select * from Employee
```

Find the solution in Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/394a9/1

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select * into #temp from @TBL
create nonclustered index Temp_Index on #temp(EmpId)

;with TBLCTE(EmpID,Ranking)
AS
(
select
EmpID,
Ranking = DENSE_RANK() over (PARTITION BY EmpID order by newID())
from #temp
)
delete from #temp where Ranking > 1

truncate table @TBL
insert into @TBL
Select * from #temp
```

Comment: We tried this and this was also taking too much time :(

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete the duplicated data in smaller chunks - make a loop and process chunks after each other. The smallest chunk is defined as all duplicates of 1 unique record...
Your statement is taking so long, because it has to create the whole snapshot in the memory.

Comment: In order to process in chunks, we need a primary key or a column that uniquely identifies each record, but adding this column and its data to the table might take too long again. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

1.Insert the distinct records in a temporary table.

2.Truncate the original table.

3.Insert back the record to the original table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT T.*
INTO #TEMPTABLE
FROM T;

TRUNCATE TABLE T;

INSERT INTO t
    SELECT tt.*
    FROM #temptable tt;
```

OR

1.Insert the distinct records in a temporary table.

2.Drop the original table.

3.Rename the temporary table

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
INTO NewTable
FROM OldTable;

DROP TABLE OldTable;

EXEC sp_rename 'OldTable', 'NewTable'
```

---

You can replace `SELECT DISTINCT` with a faster way to get distinct records. But the procedure still stays the same.

Here is super fast `DISTINCT` using recursive CTE by Paul White. See [**this**](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic873124-338-5.aspx#bm1013407) for reference:

```
CREATE  CLUSTERED INDEX c ON dbo.T(EmpID);


WITH    RecursiveCTE
AS      (
        SELECT  data = MIN(T.data)
        FROM    dbo.Test T
        UNION   ALL
        SELECT  R.data
        FROM    (
                -- A cunning way to use TOP in the recursive part of a CTE :)
                SELECT  T.data,
                        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T.data)
                FROM    dbo.Test T
                JOIN    RecursiveCTE R
                        ON  R.data < T.data
                ) R
        WHERE   R.rn = 1
        )
SELECT  *
FROM    RecursiveCTE
OPTION  (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Comment: Doing select distinct for over 500 million rows sounds quite heavy

Comment: We used group by instead of distinct, will it make difference?

Comment: You can find another way to insert `DISTINCT` records, but the idea still stays the same.